# How do I combine two vectors of different size in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm having trouble with what might be a basic concept. I would really appreciate any insight and help.

I have to define the function z=10*x*sin(⁡2*y) over the range of 0 ≤ x ≤ −1, 0 ≤ y ≤ 3. I have been specifically asked to have a vector consisting of 11, equally spaced values of 0 ≤ x ≤ −1 and another vector consisting of 31 equally spaced values of 0 ≤ y ≤ 3. Then I have to define a 31×11 matrix z, with entries z(m,k)=10*x(k)*sin(2*y(m)).

I have no idea what m and k have to do with anything. And anytime I try to insert x and y into z, I get an error message about inner dimensions.

All I have is:
x=-1:.1:0
y=0:.1:3

Answer (score 3):

Hint: see the `ndgrid()` command.

Comment: I really have no idea what I'm doing.

This is my program:     

x=-1:.1:0;     
y=0:.1:3;     

[X,Y]=ndgrid(x,y);     

z=10.*X*sin(2*Y)     

The ndgrid() command got me two 11x31 matrices, but I still get the error "Error using ==> mtimes. Inner dimensions must agree."

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `*` operator. You should be using `.*` and other element-wise operators. The example in "doc ndgrid" illustrates this and is very similar to what you are doing.

Comment: @user3266487 Actually it already seems like you tried to use this for the first multiplication. However, as that is multiplication with a scalar (unlike the second multiplication) both operators are valid.

Comment: My mistake. I forgot one period when typing z here. I am using the .* operator. This is my first time on this website so excuse my naive questions but what is "doc ngrid" and how do I get access to it? I searched for it on this site and something relating to python came up. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: If you execute `doc ndgrid` at the MATLAB command line, it will bring up HTML documentation on the ndgrid command, more detailed than what `help ndgrid` gives you.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=-1:.1:0;
y=0:.1:3;

[X,Y]=ndgrid(x,y);

Z=10*X.*sin(2*Y)
```

Don't forget the dot in ".*" when multiplying matrices element by element

Answer (score 0):

May this is the solution?! Have a look at the element-wise operator ".*"

```
x = -1:.1:0;
y = 0:.1:3;
[X,Y] = ndgrid(x,y);
z = 10*X.*sin(2*Y);
mesh(z);
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will help you! if i understood correctly:

```
x=-1:0.1:0;
y=0:0.1:3;
take_size_x=size(x,2);
take_size_y=size(y,2);

for j=1:take_size_y
    for i=1:take_size_x
z(j,i)=10*x(i)*sin(2*y(j));
    end
end
```